# basic angular 5 karma test fails

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

Given the following test `sanity.spec.ts`:

```
describe("karma sanity check",
    () => {
        it("1+1=2", () => expect(1 + 1).toBe(2));
    });
```

Karma produces this:

```
27 02 2018 09:17:53.641:INFO [bundler.karma-typescript]: Bundled imports for 3 file(s) in 2162 ms.
27 02 2018 09:17:53.645:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
27 02 2018 09:17:53.659:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
27 02 2018 09:17:53.660:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
27 02 2018 09:17:53.674:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
27 02 2018 09:17:55.126:INFO [Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket grFZALtIKw9NjBeoAAAA with id 46992309
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0) karma sanity check 1+1=2 FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of null
```

The error is in the `Zone`

[image]

My `karma.config.js` is as follows:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-typescript'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: 'base.spec.ts'},
      { pattern: 'wwwroot/ts/**/*.spec.ts' }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      "**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

base file `base.spec.ts` is this:

```
import "core-js"
import "zone.js/dist/zone";
import "zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone";
import "zone.js/dist/proxy";
import "zone.js/dist/sync-test";
import "zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch";
import "zone.js/dist/async-test";
import "zone.js/dist/fake-async-test";

import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

**edit**

> I have tried below, which doesn't seem to help - same error:

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";

describe("karma sanity check",
    () => {
        beforeEach(() =>
        {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [] });
        });

        it("1+1=2", () => expect(1 + 1).toBe(2));
    });
```

Comment: is there a tutorial anywhere on setting up karma tests without angular-cli?

Comment: any suggestions on how to simplify the question would be welcome, since I haven't even managed to get a comment yet...

Comment: I have logged a bug https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is acknowledged as a bug.
https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1015